# IMG not loading in PHASER 3? JS

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Im trying to load img in phaser, but it gives me the error GET 404 (not found) when the img exist and its in the right path, but i dont know why it isnt working, im using xampp, heres the code:

the routes:

[image]

code:

```
class Scene extends Phaser.Scene {
constructor() {
    super("Scene");  //constructor gives name to scene
}
preload() {
    this.load.image("space","img/space.png");
    //this.load.image("ship","../img/lakers_ship.png");
}
create() {
    this.add.text(20,20,"Loading...");
    this.scene.start("Scene2");
}
}



class Scene2 extends Phaser.Scene {

constructor() {
    super("Scene2");
}
create() {
    this.background = this.add.image(0,0,"space");
    this.background.setOrigin(0,0);
    //this.ship = this.add.image(50,50,"ship");
    this.add.text(0,0,"Welcome to scene 2");
    //this.input.on("pointerdown", () => this.scene.start("Scene"));
    
}
}
```

please help me, im getting crazy with it :(

Comment: `this.load.image("space", "./Shumting/img/space.png");` maybe try it like this?

Comment: `../img` is gonna give you `JS_GAME/img`? can you just console and see what path it gives you?

Comment: Reiterating the above, knowing what the browser's console is showing for the path of the 404 would be helpful.